# laravel cloned provider does not work (class not found)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I cloned a repository in github (Tightenco/ziggy) in which I made modifications to fit my use (just minor modifications which worked when i edited directly the original repo in the vendor). now I have a repo on my github account which contains my modifications.

In order to use it in my laravel project, I added theses lines to the composer.json then ran composer update:

```
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "tightenco/ziggy",
                "version": "0.5.0",
                "source": {
                    "type" : "git",
                    "url" : "git://github.com/Ctaque/ziggy.git",
                    "reference" : "master"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/Ctaque/ziggy/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
  "require": {
      ...
        "tightenco/ziggy":"0.5.*"
    },
```

now i have a vendor with tightenco/ziggy which contains the repo with my modifications.
I followed the instructions to use the dependancy in Laravel (register the provider)
And I get this error when registering the provider:

> "Class 'Tightenco\Ziggy\ZiggyServiceProvider' not found"

Any ideas? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the stuff below `repositories` and add

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Ctaque/ziggy"
    }
],
```

Remove also the cloned folder from your `vendors` dir.

Comment: Ok, I also needed to add the original package at version "dev-master" in the required package section. Thanks